# Materialize material_select() search feature

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, materialize

Is there any search functionality implemented for material_select()

I am looking for search functionality for [matrializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select) select componant

I have gone through the [repository](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) but does not found any solution.

Please suggest me the way

Comment: There is not, however you may run your own JQuery to get selected items.

Comment: @Dražen Is there any easy alternate solution so that I can implement search in dropdown?